# How can I ignore a certain WebStorm inspection error?

Tags: typescript, webstorm, rule

Following tries do not work:

```
/* tslint:disable:"no-unused-variable" */

/* tslint:disable:'no-unused-variable' */

/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */
```

[image]

Maybe Webstorm has other linting mechanisms working in the background? How can I disable them, so that only tslint is active?

**EDIT: The desired solution would be to do it at the source code level, without configuring any IDE Settings.**

Comment: Have you created your own `tslint.json` file at the root of your project folder?

Comment: yes, all the rules are working properly, I want to disable a certain one,..

Comment: Oh ok. It seems that the official documentation mentions what you're already trying: https://github.com/palantir/tslint#rule-flags

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This warning doesn't come from TSLint, so configuring TSLint won't help here. This is WebStorm own inspection error. You can either disable this inspection or suppress it for current statement: hit Alt+Enter on 'isDone', then hit Right and choose the appropriate action from the popup.  See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/suppressing-inspections.html#1

Comment: Just FYI: TSLint errors normally have 'TSLint' prefix in tooltip

Comment: Hi Lena, How can I disable that only in the current file ? Maybe in the form of, how tslint does it ?

Comment: You can select a scope for inspection: in Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes create a scope with this file excluded, then select this scope for 'Unused javaScript/ActionScript local symbol' inspection in Settings | Editor | Inspections

Comment: this can't be done using comments. You can suppress it for current statement, but not for current file

Comment: WebStorm 2016.3 seems useless in this respect on MacOS anyway, unless I've missed some hidden configuration option. No popup exists to apply an inspection override.

Comment: as you can see in my solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795435/how-can-i-ignore-a-certain-webstorm-inspection-error/40770509#40770509), it can be done using comments ;)

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with

```
//noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
```

in Webstorm version 2016.3

To get this code, i used:

```
ALT + Enter
Select "Remove unused constant 'xxx'" but dont Enter
Arrow right
Suppress for statement
```

[image: Suppress for statement]

Comment: How to undo suppress for this statement?

Comment: Delete the comment `//noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols`

Answer (score 0):

> *"[tslint] " should be ' (quotemark)*

In order to fix *"[tslint] " should be ' (quotemark)* error open `tslint.json` file and set `editor.formatOnSave` to `true` as shown below:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true
```